# Object height is 15% less than line-height on cordova android app

Tags: android, css, cordova

as you can see on pictures line-height of p is not equal to p height, there is always a 15% difference, that happens only on android devices.

On iPhone, chrome, safari and even on android with crosswalk works as it should. Anyone knows why? It's a bug?